# What's the threat model of mobile security?

Tags: mobile, threat-modeling, mobile-app

When reading about mobile security, the attacker is often assumed to have root access to the device, so as to patch the application or proxy all network traffic.

I see that such applications may have generic vulnerabilities, like non-encrypted traffic or insecure storage, but how is the application supposed to stay secure given that its underlying platform is compromised?

What's the threat model of mobile security, and why does it seemingly include actors with root access to the device?

Comment: *"Mobile Security"* is a  wide field with different scenarios and different threat models. While you don't provide any details (i.e. missing focus) my guess is that the assumptions you ask about are in the context of securing applications on the device against the owner of the device, i.e. DRM, preventing manipulation of games ... . It is usually a reasonable assumption that the owner of the device could also root it in order to bypass restrictions done locally by the application.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you see this?

Comment: The attacker doesn't have root by default, it's a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single threat model for "mobile security", any more than there is a threat model for "workstation security". Your threat model depends on *your* circumstances.

If your starting point is that the attacker has root access to the underlying operating system then you've pretty much lost. There are things that you can do to make it harder and more time-consuming for them to attack your app, but ultimately if they have root they can get around any local controls that you put in place. So in that case, your security should be built around the assumption that everything on the endpoint is compromised and untrusted, and that any information received from the endpoint is untrusted.

But if your app is Flappy Bird 2.0 then you probably don't care that much - which is why you need to consider your own circumstances.